# How can I center horizontally but not vertically?

Tags: vertical-alignment, diagrams, horizontal-alignment

This centers both horizontally and vertically, but I do not want vertical centering. I want the grid to be at the top of the page. (The geometry package works well at defining margins though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=5pt,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \begin{centering}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=(3/10)]

      \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (670mm,700mm);

    \end{tikzpicture}

  \caption{some caption here}

  \end{centering}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need it to be floating or should it be in a fixed position in the document?

Comment: Not sure, but I do need room at bottom for captions. I think fixed is ok cause evry page will be the same , just one picture.

Comment: In this case a figure environment is not required. figures like here may be vertically centered on float pages. But I edit my answer to be more detailed.

Answer (score 5):

One single character would make a difference: try `\begin{figure}[ht!]` instead. By adding this option the picture would float to the top of the page.

However, because the picture doesn't need to float across page borders and should be just at the top, you don't need a figure environment. Instead, you could use the `\captionof` command of the `caption` package, which you're already loading. Here's a small example based on your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=5pt,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=(3/10)]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (670mm,700mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{some caption here}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```